# What is the icon to indicate 'presets' for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, icons

What is the name of this icon?

[image: Presets icon]

I want an icon to indicate 'user preferences' (i.e. presets).

According to Google, this is a standard presets icon, but I can't find it in Icons or font_awesome_flutter. --Or is there another icon more commonly used?

```
iconData: Icons.presets ///Not an option
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) package. The icon name is `sliders`

```dart
    FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.sliders),
```

[image]

[Website](https://fontawesome.com/icons/sliders?s=solid&f=classic) helps to find icon.

Answer (score 1):

In font awesome website it is called `sliders`
In flutter it is called `Tune` - `Icon(Icons.tune)`

Answer (score 0):

You can download this icon in SVG format and use it by https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg